# net share in windows actual path

Tags: path, internet-sharing, unc, computing-environment

I have a UNC Share folder with the following path

```
\\192.168.0.100\SharedTemp\MuhammedRauf\UNC
```

How do I know the physical path of the above (using `net share` or any other tools in Windows 7)?

Comment: It would be good to know if you are referring to your local machine or another machine in the network. The second option is tougher to accomplish, see my answer below for possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these :

- Run `cmd` to get to a command prompt. From there you type `net share`. In the first column it shows the name of the share and the second column shows the actual location.
- Run `regedit` to get to the registry database. From there navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\LanmanServer\Shares**

---

The solutions below does not work properly, but since you are running Windows7 you could try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) like this: `psexec -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD \\REMOTE-PC net share`

**EDIT: The script below does not work properly**

These methods only work if you are referring to UNC paths on your local machine. If not you should upload a small visual basic script and name it **showcurrentfolder.vbs** :

```
currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))
WScript.Echo currentDirectory
```

All you need to do now is navigate to your UNC path above and run it.

---

**EDIT: The script below does not work properly**

Try this if the network pc is running Linux/Mac:

Upload this small script as **showcurrentfolder.htm** and run it :

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var path = location.pathname;
document.write("<center>" + path + "</center>");
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD></HTML>
```

Comment: I created the file and ran it. It comes and closes very quickly.

Comment: Try the new solution i just added.

Comment: The network pc is running windows 7. I got the following when I opened "showcurrentfolder.htm"                                /SharedTemp/MuhammedRauf/UNC/path.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the pc that act as a "file server" I do this using right click on computer and then I select "Manage" and then in shares you can find where the share is stored on physical disk.
This also work (if you have user/pass) connecting your microsoft management console (mmc.exe) to a remote host.

Just ask for any details: I'll be glad to help :)